# Javascript determine if such object property exists based on a string

Tags: javascript

We have a module that allows users to create some scripts.

I would like to determine if user has used correct properties etc.

For example user has wrote:

```
var test = session;
```

I can do:

```
var something = eval("session");
if (!something){
    // Throw error here
}
```

But i'm facing issues with this:

```
var test = session.id; // session id property is "id123456"
```

I thought i can do:

```
var something = eval("session.id");
if (!something){
    // Throw error here
}
```

But it seems it really does this:

```
var something = eval("id123456");
```

**Any suggestions how can i determine wheter property exist in this object, also property in property and further?**

As i said, i'm not trying to determine some certain object for some certain property, the strcture can be:

session.id.toString().name ... and further

In addition, i have just tried this:

```
session.hasOwnProperty("id"); // returned false

session.id // returned "id123456"
```

Comment: what is wrong with simply using `session[id][name]...`? I really don't see why eval would be needed here

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```js
eval('var session = {id:"id1234"}');
var x = eval("session")
console.warn(eval("x.id"))
console.error(eval("x.id.toString()"))
console.log(x.id)
```

Comment: Yeah, okay, but how can i write the id as a string, not a predefined property in my JS?

For example: session.id.toString().name - i need dynamic check

Comment: I added code for you.This support `session.id.toString()` too ;)

Comment: when i do eval(session.id) it shows errors in console:
id123456 does not exist

It uses the property value for evaluation

Comment: What do you want that eval to return?

Comment: I answered based on your question and developed some real example.But I don't know what is your purpose.There must be `session` variable out there to evaluate values attached to it